# MSBuild | Property Value Is Empty After Being Set

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

## Background

I am very new to MSBUild and I am attempting to write an MSBuild script with a post build event. Prior to the post build event, I want to obtain some version information (the version itself, then each segment of the version).

## Problem

I can get the version successfully, but when trying to set properties based on the parts of the version, the properties are blank.

## Code

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
        $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
        PostBuildMacros;
    </PostBuildEventDependsOn>

    <PostBuildEvent>
        if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
            // This shows the correct version
            echo THE ASSEMBLY VERSION IS: @(VersionNumber)

            // This is blank
            echo THE MAJOR VERSION IS: $(MajorVersion)
        )
    </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>

    <ItemGroup>
        <VersionNumber Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)')" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <MajorVersion>$([System.Version]::Parse(%(Targets.Version)).Major)</MajorVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: This is a classical evaluation order problem; I don't know by heart which rule in the docs states this but the key is that PostBuildEvent is a global property and the properties used within it are evaluated/expanded *before* the execution of targets and consecutive evaluation/expansion of properties within those targets - while for items this isslightly different, as you noticed. One easy way to solve this: use `<Target Name="PostBuildMacros" AfterTargets="Build">` and mimick your PostBuildEvent using e.g. `<Exec Command="echo $(MajorVersion)"/>` in that target.

Comment: Btw you did a fine job in describing problem and code, but did not mention an actual question :]

Comment: @stijn I know your comment is very old, but I didn't see it before about no actual question. The question is self-explanatory and listed under the Problem section. Generally, describing the problem AND asking "how do I fix the problem I described" is redundant